# QML On Item Changed Signal

Tags: qt, signals, qml

*MyObject*

```
Item {
    property int current: 0
}
```

Can this be configured to emit a signal such that the following works?

```
Item {
    property variant myObj: MyObject {}
    onMyObjChanged: doThis()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not without manually forwarding every property change signal to your custom `MyObj` signal.  I have to question _why_ you would want to do this?

Comment: I am on a legacy project and have not used Qt/QML before. The on<Property>Changed pattern is in use throughout. Without knowledge of best practices with these tools, I am looking for ways to inform the owner of an Item-based property that its internal state has changed. In this case, only `current` is relevant to the "state" of MyObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmannet85 has answered your question: it's not possible. Perhaps you could post more code so we can suggest alternative approaches.

In terms of a solution using the information you've provided, you should expose signals that client code should connect to in order to know when the object has changed. Since you said the `current` property is all that matters, and it [already has a change signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#property-change-signal-handlers), you can use `Connections`:

```
Connections {
    target: myObj
    onCurrentChanged: doThis()
}
```

Or connect to the signal manually:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    myObj.onCurrentChanged.connect(doThis);
}

function doThis() {
    // ...
}
```